# Returning the other value of the pair from a tuple, which has closest value to certain number

Tags: python, tuples

I have a `list` of `tuples` like this:

```
[(78, 10), (84, 11), (75, 12), (78, 13), (75, 14), (77, 15), (79, 16), (81, 17), (83, 18), (85, 19)]
```

How can I do like, if the first number in any of the `tuples` is closest/equal to a certain number, return the other pair value from that tuple?

for example in the list above:

certain number: 79
then it should return 16 from the above list.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I can compare value with a list and return the closest like this:
```print (min(my_list, key=lambda x: abs(x - certainvalue)``` but since that's for single values, I don't know how to isolate the value from a tuple compare to certain value, and then return the pair value

Comment: What if the number was 78?  What if it was 82?

Comment: this was just an example, I just to find a way to isolate the first value from the tuples, compare to certain value, and return the other value from the tuple

Comment: What is your logic to determine closest when equal is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

### Method 1:

Iterate over the list and check for the smallest difference.

```
def return_closest_pair(data: list, target: int) -> int:
    closest, other = data[0]
    closest_diff = abs(closest - target)
    rest = iter(data[1:])
    for left, right in rest:
        diff = abs(left - target)
        if diff < closest_diff:
            closest, other = left, right
    return other

>>> return_closest_pair(data, 79)
```

### Method 2:

Write a custom key for `min` function, as you had originally tried.

```
def find_closest_to(target):
    def comp(tup):
        left, right = tup
        return abs(left - target)
    return comp

>>> min(data, key=find_closest_to(79))[0]
16
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
l = [(78, 10), (84, 11), (75, 12), (78, 13), (75, 14), (77, 15), (79, 16), (81, 17), (83, 18), (85, 19)]
n = 79
diff = 10**6
ans = 0
for i in l:
    if abs(n-i[0])< diff:
        diff = abs(n-i[0])
        ans = i[1]
        
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
16
```

Comment: Thanks man, can you please explain what is ```diff = 10**6``` ?